# Can't detect string using error handling and cant make "For" loop to work

Tags: javascript, html

I was given the following task:

> You will need to ask user to give you an integer. Use error handling to check if the user is submitting an integer, if not, display an error message. Then, use a for loop to give the user the first 100 multipliers of that integer.

I've been trying to fix this for hours and I can't seem to get most of it right.
Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Index_loop_1</title>
  </head>
  
  <body style = "background-color: #000000">
    <h1 id="ha" style="color:#ffffff ;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif ;text-align: center; font-size:250%; padding: 250px 0">a</h1>
    <script>
      var a = document.getElementById("ha")
      var m = "That is not a number!"
      var f = window.prompt("Type a number here:")
      
      try {
        f = Integer.parseInt("100");
      } catch(NumberFormatException) {
        a.innerHTML = m
        window.stop()
      }
      
      for (var q = f; q < 100; q *= q) {
        a.innerHTML += q
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if getting "the first 100 multipliers" is what we are doing here (as we are getting squares of that number < 100), maybe it's "multiples"?

Anyways, isn't the idea to solve that for you, but code problems:

- We should be using `parseInt()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()`, [MDN Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). `Integer.parseInt` comes from Java, not JavaScript.
- `NumberFormatException` is also a Java feature.
- Inside `try` we are overwriting the input number to 100.
- I encourage you to use *human-readable* variable names.

An example of the same script but the `JavaScript` way and some fixes:

```js
const error = "That is not a number!";
let factor = window.prompt("Type a number here:");
// Take integer part of factor, or NaN (not a number).
let factorInt = parseInt(factor);

if (isNaN(factorInt)) {
  console.log(error, factor);
} else if (factorInt > 1) {
  // If (factorInt <= 1) we get an infinite loop!
  for (let total = factorInt; total < 100; total *= total) {
    console.log(total);
  }
}
```